# AwsSignatureVersion4 PostAsync leaves null Authorization header

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, sigv4

I'm attempting to POST a graphql query to an aws appsync application. I'm using the AwsSignatureVersion4 HttpClient extensions (PostAsync) to sign the request before sending it.

My request is returning an empty list of objects, even though I know there are objects on the server. While investigating this, I noticed that in my response object, `response.RequestMessage.Headers.Authorization` is null. If I look in `response.RequestMessage.Headers.headerStore`, I have an entry:

`Key: "Authorization"`
`Value: {System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.HeaderStoreItemInfo}`
`-> ParsedValue: null`
`-> invalidValue: {the actual signature}`

So it appears that there's something about this signature that the system doesn't like. I don't know whether the actual message had a valid Authorization header.

Does anyone have any insight to share? Has anyone used this PostAsync extension successfully?